# Determining silverlight control's size

Tags: silverlight, canvas, controls, size

I'm an experienced programmer, but completely new to the world of Silverlight.   I've been tasked with fixing a problem in a Silverlight application, and am struggling to find the information I need.

The app contains a custom control, upon which pop-up tooltips can be displayed near the mouse cursor. I need to ensure the tooltips get positioned in such a way that they don't exceed the bounds of the control. Easy, in theory, however I can't figure out how to get the size of the control.

It's declared in some XAML, like this (main control name changed to 'XXX' for privacy):

```
<client:XxxHost x:Class="Project.Client.Banana"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:xxx="clr-namespace:Project.Controls;assembly=Project.Controls.Xxx"
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Project.Controls.UI;assembly=Project.Controls.UI"
    xmlns:client="clr-namespace:Project.Client"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
<xxx:XxxControl x:Name="XxxControl">
    <xxx:XxxControl.UI>
        <ui:Banana DataContext="{Binding}" View="{Binding View}" />
    </xxx:XxxControl.UI>
    <xxx:XxxControl.TooltipDisplay>
        <xxx:MultiTooltipDisplay></xxx:MultiTooltipDisplay>
    </xxx:XxxControl.TooltipDisplay>
</xxx:XxxControl>
</client:XxxHost>
```

In the code,  MultiTooltipDisplay is a class derived from Canvas.  In its method to display a tooltip, it has this code:

```
    public void DisplayTooltips(System.Collections.Generic.List<UIElement> tooltips, Point screenAnchor)
    {
        ClearTooltips();

        if (tooltips.Count > 0)
        {
            StackPanel ttStack = new StackPanel();
            ttStack.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            for (int i = 0; i < tooltips.Count; i++)
            {
                UIElement ttip = tooltips[ i ];
                UserControl ttipWrapper = new UserControl();
                ttipWrapper.Content = ttip;
                ttStack.Children.Add(ttipWrapper);
            }
            ttStack.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, screenAnchor.Y);
            ttStack.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, screenAnchor.X + 24.0); 
            this.Children.Add(ttStack);
         }
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint in towards the end of this method, and I inspect ttStack's `Width/Height/ActualWidth/ActualHeight/DesiredSize`, I find they're all 0 or NaN. After some reading and trial & error I found out that by putting in a call to  ttStack.UpdateLayout() those values would get populated. I'm not sure if that's the correct way, but the numbers seem reasonable. Great!

However, I need to know the size of the control upon which the tooltip would be displayed, but I get the same issue. this.Width/Height/etc all return 0 or NaN.  A call to this.UpdateLayout() doesn't change those properties.

How can I determine the dimensions of the contol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the `Measure` method on ttStack before reading is `DesiredSize`.

Comment: Well that sets ttStack's DesiredSize/ActualWidth/ActualHeight, but I was already getting those if I called UpdateLayout().
The question was about the canvas (i.e. 'this'), and how I can find its size.

Comment: @Dave: Canvas only ever has the size you give it or if unassigned the size given it by the container. It does not grow with the extent of its content.  Perhaps you would be better off deriving from Grid?

Comment: But if the Canvas has a size, no matter where it got it, can I not query it to find out how big it is, or how big its container is? 
Deriving from Grid might be an alternative (if it supports absolute placement of it's children - I'd need to read up on it), but at the moment I'm just trying to fix what should be a simple bug (if only I could measure things properly!) and re-writing the code to use a different base class when I don't really know much Silverlight yet seems like a large task, especially when I don't understand what effect that might have on the rest of the application

Comment: @Dave: as test add a background color to you canvas.  Do you see that color at runtime? My guess is no.  Yet the canvas displays its content fine.  The content of a canvas is not limited to the display area given to it.  Hence a canvas can be zero size yet its content render happily.  I suspect you are readin the canvas size fine, it just happens to be 0.

Comment: You must first: 
1. add the control to visual tree (for example as child of some ItemsControl 
2. then call your control's Measure method with large Size instance as parameter for example:
control.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity,double.PositiveInfinity));

After this you can check its DesiredSize property to see whats this controls size.

This way control will try to stretch inside the size you gave it (infinite space) and occupy space it needs.

If you want it to have limits in size then use those limits when calling Measure.

Answer (score 0):

I used `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, it worked for me.